# Check MYSQL to see if a entry already exists without if else

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a long page of code with multiple if else statemets, what i would like to do is check a database to see if that Ip address is already in the table

currently i am doing it like this

```
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM masterip_details WHERE    ip_address='$ip_address' AND client_id='$client_id'") or die(mysql_error());
     $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    //IF THE RESULT IS MORE THAN 0, THIS MEANS THAT THEY ARE A RETURNING VISITOR
    if( $num_rows > 0 ) {
         /// Add returning Script here  

    }  else {
        //Add code

         }
```

Is there a way i could do this with out the if else statement?, so for example if the record was in the database just return a value of 1.

Thanks, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you still need an `if` statement to read that `1`?

Comment: `return ($num_rows > 0);` will return a true or false to the caller

Comment: You can do it in 1 statement, but it cause problem when it throw error from `mysql_query`

Comment: Better select `COUNT()`. Unless `ip_address` is unique in the database, you could be potentially fetching quite a bunch of rows unnecessarily.

Comment: Also please note, that the ip adress changes from time to time, so thats no reliable option on finding a returning customer.

Comment: Thanks, for all the advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` to get the number of rows with that value.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM masterip_details WHERE    ip_address='$ip_address' AND client_id='$client_id'") or die(mysql_error());

return $result > 0;  //returns a boolean
```

This way you will get a `0` if the value doesn't exist on the database and a number higher than 0 if it does.

Comment: Ok sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do i capture the value of result as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **`SELECT IF EXISTS`** on MySQL.

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             FROM  masterip_details
             WHERE `ip_address`=? AND `client_id`=?), 1, 0)
```